# Fill text input field with posted form data from previous page

Tags: html, forms, post, input, get

I have a form action that posts to a second page with a form on it with more info.

How can I pull (I guess "get") the info from the previous page's form fields into new fields on this second page?

Comment: Check out an example: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp

Comment: Thanks! Is this only possible with PHP?

Comment: @Reuben You can do it with any server-side language. But if it's your question, you can't do it with only html/css/client side javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will depend on how you're processing the forms.  Your server-side scripting platform (e.g. PHP) will provide a way to access the POST data to render into the next page.

If you're just writing static HTML without a server-side component, this won't be possible.

Comment: Are there any ready made scripts/things (I'm front end) that would make this (processing forms) easy?

Answer (score 0):

When you post a form, that means you are sending data to your back-end. To capture that data, you need to process it on the server using a server-side language like **PHP**. So, assuming you are using **PHP**, You would get the posted data using:

```
<?
$name = $_POST['name']; //if the form method is set to post
$name = $_GET['name'];  //if the form method is set to get
?>
```

`$_POST` array will hold the data you send using a **POST** http request while the `$_GET` array will hold the data you send using a **GET** http request.